# ¿Cómo agregar atributo a documento XML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml, xpath

Tengo un documento XML en una ubicación de mi ordenador, y necesitó agregar un nuevo atributo a un elemento.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

por ejemplo se ve asi:

```
<padre>
  <hijo id="576hsdj"> 
  </hijo>
</padre>
```

nesecito que se vea asi:

```
<padre>
   <hijo id="576hsdj" type="modeloAAA"> 
   </hijo>
</padre>
```

El codigo que tengo es este:

```
private string AtributoAdd(string path,XmlDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            string result = "";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(path);
            try
            {
                string uri = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
                XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                nsManager.AddNamespace("ds",uri);
                XmlNode Transform = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ds:NombreAtributo", nsManager);

            //CODIGO QUE NESECITO 

            xmlDoc.Save(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { result = ex.ToString(); }
            return result;

        }
```

Comment: Has intentado algo? Has intentado buscar información antes de preguntar aqui? Has leido [ask]?

Comment: Consegui como construirlo desde LInq ...pero no despues de guardado

Comment: Listo ya agregue lo q tengo escrito...

Answer (score 2):

Para agregarle un atributo, depende de si lo tenés como nodo o como elemento:

1. **`XmlElement`**

   Si se trata de un [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx), simplemente se llama a [`.SetAttribute(atr,namespace,valor)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ec5ak8h6(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
   elementoHijo.SetAttribute("type","ds","modeloAAA");
   ```

   o sin namespace:

   ```
   elementoHijo.SetAttribute("type","modeloAAA");
   ```

2. **`XmlNode`**

   Si se trata de un [XmlNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx), como en tu caso, hay que generar un [XmlAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), y asignarlo con [`.Attributes.SetNamedItem(atributo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.setnameditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
   //seleccionar el nodo
   XmlNode nodoHijo = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='576hsdj']");

   //agregarle el atributo
   XmlAttribute atr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("type");
   atr.Value = "modeloAAA";
   nodoHijo.Attributes.SetNamedItem(atr);
   ```

   Demo:
   https://ideone.com/ZTZGUm

3. **`XmlNode`** → **`XmlElement`**

   O podrías hacer un cast a XmlElement y usar el primer método, pero para eso tendrías que estar completamente seguro de que el nodo es un elemento (o capturar el error):

   ```
   //agregarle el atributo
   XmlElement elemHijo = (XmlElement)nodoHijo;
   elemHijo.SetAttribute("type","modeloAAA");
   ```

   Demo:
   https://ideone.com/gDBksx